# Se puede procesar un XML dentro de un archivo 7z más rápido?

Tags: go

Quiero cargar el [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) en una base de datos mysql.

Arranqué con el archivo [stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z) porque es uno de los más interesantes y tiene un tamaño que me permite jugar con las optimizaciones (10 GB comprimido).

El `7z` contiene sólo un archivo, `Posts.xml`... y si no hago nada con las líneas (sólo las recorro) apenas puedo leer 1 millón de registros por minuto. Estoy usando [lzmadec](https://github.com/kjk/lzmadec) que termina [llamando al ejecutable 7z](https://github.com/kjk/lzmadec/blob/master/lzmadec.go#L239).

Poner el case dentro de una `goroutine` no cambia nada (lo que está costando es descomprimir el archivo).

Hay algo que pueda hacer para mejorar el tiempo que tarda en recorrer el archivo SIN descomprimir el XML a disco y SIN consumir cantidades excesivas de memoria? este es el ejemplo más chico con el que se puede reproducir esto:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kjk/lzmadec"
    "encoding/xml"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    archive, _ := lzmadec.NewArchive("./stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z")

    for _, e := range archive.Entries {
        r, _ := archive.GetFileReader(e.Path)
        decoder := xml.NewDecoder(r)

        start := time.Now()
        row := 0

        for {
            t, _ := decoder.Token()
            if t == nil {
                break
            }

            switch se := t.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                if se.Name.Local == "row" {
                    row++
                    if row % 10000 == 0 {
                        elapsed := time.Since(start)
                        fmt.Println(row, elapsed)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```